# add clickable buttons to ionic 2 card programmatically

Tags: html, ionic-framework, ionic2, angular-promise

I have an HTML template, *details.html*, that includes this:

```
  <ion-card>{...first card on page...}</ion-card>

  <ion-card [hidden]="showColorBool">
    <ion-card-header>
       Select a color
    </ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-content>
       <!-- buttons should go here -->
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>

  <ion-card>{...next card on page...}</ion-card>
```

I need to add the buttons as indicated above. They will be will be styled according to values contained in the details array I have stored in local storage like this:

```
<button ion-button color={{data[index][color]></button>
```

I am able to access the arrays and values I need from storage like this in my *details.ts*:

```
arr.then( data => {
    console.log(data);
    for ( let index in data ){
       console.log(data[index][color]);
    }
  });
```

1) The number of buttons is always dynamic (0-10).
2) The "color" value is needed to set the color value of the buttons.
3) I can't not put this functionality in it's own component/page. It needs to be on the page with the other cards.

Any idea on how I might accomplish this? I have been through the docs and SO for everything I could find. Couldn't really find much on this dynamic stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ngFor** is what you are after.

ngFor directive: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgFor-directive.html

The ngFor directive allows you to loop through an array in the template.

**details.html**

```
<button *ngFor="let item of data" ion-button color="{{item[color]}}"></button>
```

Comment: Thanks @Carlton. You answer helped solve the issue. I was looking right past putt in tthe ngFor in the button. However, in case any other noobs have this issue, I need to point out that the further problem was the placement of my promise code, I had it in my _ionViewDidEnter_ function which was too later in the life-cycle. Place it in _ionViiewDidLoad_ or before. Also, the html syntax, in my case, needed to be this: `<button ion-button *ngFor="let item of colorOptions" [style.background]="item.color"></button>`